# How can i get all logcat entries stored to a file in android

Tags: java, android, logcat

When i use command prompt on PC and connect device and run abd to execute below command

```
abd logcat -d > abc.txt
```

It returns a big file "abc.txt" with all the entries of logcat of all apps. But when I run the same command in an app on android to store it on SD card by making a file it just stores the recent logcat entries and only logs for this app and not even previous logs. Can somebody tell me why is this happening I have also given permission to READ_LOGS

Here is the android code

```
 String fullName = "appLog.txt";
    File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fullName);

    //clears a file
    if(file.exists()){
        file.delete();
    }


    //write log to file
    try {
        String command = String.format("logcat -d");        
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String currentLine = null;

        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                   result.append(currentLine);
                   result.append("\n");

        }

        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);
        out.write(result.toString());
        out.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    //clear the log
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jelly Bean this has changed. App can read only it's own logs and don't need anymore READ_LOGS permission.

As alternative you can use [log4j for android](https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/). You can use file appender to store all the logs in some file and also `LogCatAppender` to print logs to logcat, so you can watch logs while developement within eclipse for e.g.

For catching all uncaught exceptions you can create class that implements [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) and then use it with Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(). This is then useful for printing crash reports (stack traces) to your log and/or to separate file.

Comment: But can an app read its own previous logs. I mean i run an app it reads logs only which occur in this execution i want the apps logs on all previous executions too is that possible?

Comment: Since log file is rotated you probably see all the app logs that you can in the moment of retrieving.

Comment: any way to get all logs because i want the crash info from logs... How to get all logs for this app?

Comment: I edited answer, you can use UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Comment: But some crashes like native OS related memory related crashes are not caught here i already had it in my code thats why i wanted androids logcat entire history for my app

Comment: Then you're talking about system (not app) logs related to your app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68794/discussion-between-syed-wajahat-ali-and-dario).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void appendLog(String text)
    {       
       File logFile = new File("/sdcard/log.txt");
       if (!logFile.exists())
       {
          try
          {
             logFile.createNewFile();
          } 
          catch (IOException e)
          {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
       try
       {
          BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
          buf.append(text);
          buf.newLine();
          buf.close();
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

And use the method to log from anywhere you need.

```
appendLog("your message" + anyvalueyouwanttolog );
```

Comment: The problem in my case is i want to catch and get the logfile when  i get a crash in above code the crash will not be accounted for...